# jQuery appendTo only works first time, then replaces

Tags: jquery, jquery-clone

I'm trying to use jQuery to append a cloned div at the end of a form. Here's how it works:

```js
 var student_number = 1;
    var orig_student = $("#student-1").clone();

    $("#add-student-link").click(function() {
         ++student_number;
         orig_student.appendTo('form.reg').attr('id', 'student-' + (student_number)).addClass("additional-student");
    });
```

And this works great the first time, I get a div that looks like this:

```html
<div id="student-2" class="additional-student"></div>
```

But after that, the div gets replaced with another div with the id "student-3". student-3 should have been a new div, not replaced student-2. Any ideas?

Comment: `appendTo` doesn't clone the element. You should clone before appending, not once in the beginning.

Comment: From the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/): *"If an element selected this way is inserted into a single location elsewhere in the DOM, it will be moved into the target (not cloned)"*. After the first click, `orig_student` is part of the DOM, so it is moved (albeit to the same position). Fix: `orig_student.clone().appendTo('form.reg')...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just moving the clone instead of duplicating (see the comments left below your question).

```
$("#add-student-link").click(function() {
     ++student_number;
     $("#student-1").clone().attr('id', 'student-' + (student_number)).addClass("additional-student").appendTo('form.reg');
});
```

If you're cloning to keep a copy that's clean (could be input fields in the element for all I know) then clone the clone.

```
var orig_student = $("#student-1").clone().attr('id','');
$("#add-student-link").click(function() {
     ++student_number;
     orig_student.clone().attr('id', 'student-' + (student_number)).addClass("additional-student").appendTo('form.reg');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When you click the first time, it works because it uses the cloned div.

By clicking for the second time, then the variable `orig_student` still references the same div and you are appending it again and changing the class.

To make it work you need to create another clone to append inside the function. Because that is what is going to be executed on click.

```
var student_number = 1;
var orig_student = $("#student-1"); // No need to clone it here

$("#add-student-link").click(function() {
     ++student_number;
     // Create a new clone of your original div and append it
     // Like this we clone it only when really needed
     orig_student.clone().appendTo('form.reg').attr('id', 'student-' + (student_number)).addClass("additional-student");
});
```